# How to include multiple pipeline scripts into jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a jenkins file as below

```
pipelineJob('My pipeline job'){
displayName('display name')
logRotator {
    numToKeep(10)
    daysToKeep(30)
    artifactDaysToKeep(7)
    artifactNumToKeep(1)
}
definition{
    cps {
        script(readFileFromWorkspace('./cicd/pipelines/clone_git_code.groovy'))
        script(readFileFromWorkspace('./cicd/pipelines/install_dependencies_run_quality_checks.groovy'))
    }
}
}
```

with above jenkinsfile the last `script` file is replacing other scripts.
Basically I have split tasks into multiple groovy files so that i wont repeat the same code in all jenkinsfile and reuse the same for other jobs as well, like I can now use the `clone_git_code.groovy` script in dev build as well as QA builds.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use shared libraries (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). You can define multiple groovy files with classes to return a processed object or simply creating calls with method where you define a step and the execution will be sequential.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for an answer to this, you can load a groovy file or multiple groovy files into your pipeline with the load command:

```
def setupGitCredentials = load 'jenkins/setup-git-credentials.groovy'
```

See also the examples provided by jenkins, for a more complete picture: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/pipeline-examples/load-from-file/pipeline.groovy

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue when trying to include multiple scripts into a Jenkins job. After doing some research, I found the below solution to be the simplest:

```
        definition {
            cps {
                script (
                    ScriptsLibrary.pipelineTest('did it work?') +
                    ScriptsLibrary.scmConf('repoURL_input', 'accessCredentials', 'activeBranch')
                )               
            }
        }
```

Add the "+" to concatenate the Strings. Got the job done for me :)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution,but I have absolutely no clue about what you are doing here. Could you please explain it a bit?

Comment: This looks intriguing, but this example is very incomplete. Can you provide a thorough example of what you are doing here?